# How can I get Visual Studio 2005 running on Windows 7?

Tags: visual-studio-2005, windows-7

Vista's user account protection caused problems with Visual Studio 2005, and Microsoft addressed this with the Visual Studio 2005 Service Pack 1 Update for Windows Vista.  I'm having similiar problems running VS2005 on Windows 7, but I can't find any info from Microsoft directly addressing this.  Should I just install the Vista service pack onto Windows 7?

Thanks,
Phil

Comment: Do you mean the *Visual Studio* Service Pack?  You can't install a Vista Service Pack onto Windows 7.

Comment: @reuben yes you can. see my answer

Answer (score 3):

The Visual Studio 2005 Service Pack 1 Update for Windows Vista works fine on Windows 7.  (At least, that's what I've been using, and it hasn't broken for me for any C++ or C# development.)

Answer (score 1):

you need to install the following below in the following order to get VS 2005 running properly on Windows 7.

1. VS 2005 SP1
   http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?DisplayLang=en&id=5553
2. Visual Studio 2005 Service Pack 1 Update for Windows Vista - http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=7524

Comment: Unfortunately, both these links are dead by 2021.

Comment: @AlKepp Yeah time to move on. Or download Oracle's VirtualWindows app and install an ISO of Windows Vista?

Comment: The problem is not with hosting system. VS2005 is the latest one where C++ compiler and libraries support all older versions of Windows. When you want to compile some old stuff, sometimes you do projects which are related for example with old hardware and you simply don't want to lose this compatibility. So you need VS2005. It is not clear to me why Microsoft is hassling with Service packs, it is very dangerous to let people download them from untrusted online sources, possibly infected with viruses.